# Why does Ubuntu 18.04 fan always running at -1 RPM? (On Asus)

Tags: 18.04, asus, overheating, fan, temperature

I have a problem, it seems that my laptop fan does not run at all.

[image]

Running pwmconfig gives me:

> Found the following devices:    hwmon0 is acpitz    hwmon1 is coretemp
>   hwmon2 is asus    hwmon3 is iwlwifi
>
> Found the following PWM controls:    hwmon2/pwm1           current
>   value: 255
>
> Giving the fans some time to reach full speed... Found the following
>   fan sensors:    hwmon2/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
>
> There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0. Make sure you
>   have a 3-wire fan connected. You may also need to increase the fan
>   divisors. See doc/fan-divisors for more information.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? Because I think 50-60 degress with -1 rpm fan is normal?